# Query to get the counts of all the objects in a Snowflake database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Output be like: (Database: Snowflake)

```
SchemaName   TablesPerSchema ViewsPerSchema Procedures
------------ --------------- -------------- -----------
abcd        46              117            163
GDS          0               3              3
IATA         3               10             13
Integration  2               4              6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema.html) views:

```
SELECT 
    T.TABLE_CATALOG, T.TABLE_SCHEMA
   ,COUNT_IF(T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE')               AS TablesPerSchema
   ,COUNT_IF(T.TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW')                     AS ViewsPerSchema
   ,MAX(SELECT COUNT(P.PROCEDURE_NAME)
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES P
        WHERE T.TABLE_CATALOG = P.PROCEDURE_CATALOG
          AND T.TABLE_SCHEMA = P.PROCEDURE_SCHEMA)      AS ProceduresPerSchema
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
GROUP BY T.TABLE_CATALOG, T.TABLE_SCHEMA
ORDER BY T.TABLE_CATALOG, T.TABLE_SCHEMA;
```

Output:

[image]

Additional object types could be added(if required):

```
,MAX(SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FUNCTIONS F
     WHERE T.TABLE_CATALOG = F.FUNCTION_CATALOG
       AND T.TABLE_SCHEMA = F.FUNCTION_SCHEMA)      AS FunctionsPerSchema
```